# prev_entry and next_entry not returning correct site_index path

Tags: next-prev, 2.9

I'm showing single entries on my site index page and for each entry my url looks like this: `index.php/entry_url_title`.

The EE docs say that I can use `{path='site_index'}` as a variable in `{exp:channel:prev_entry}` and `{exp:channel:next_entry`}, however that doesn't seem to be working for me.

`{path='site_index'}` is returning: `index.php/site_index/next_entry_url_title` Not the expected: `index.php/next_entry_url_title`.

`{path='site_index'}` is working correctly outside the `next_entry` and `prev_entry` tags.

I'm running EE2.9.2
Any thoughts?

**Per Marks request I'm including my template code, stripped down to the essentials:**

```
{layout="home/layout"}  
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}  
{case value="''"}  
    <!-- List of Entries -->  
{/case}{case default="yes"}  
    <div class="content wrap">  
        <div class="pagination top">  
        {exp:channel:next_entry channel="work" url_title="{segment_1}"}  
            <a href="{path='site_index'}" class="left">Next - {title}</a>  
        {/exp:channel:next_entry}  
        {exp:channel:prev_entry channel="work" url_title="{segment_1}"}  
            <a href="{path='site_index'}" class="right">Prev - {title}</a>  
        {/exp:channel:prev_entry}  
        </div>  
    {exp:channel:entries channel="work" url_title="{segment_1}" limit="1"}  
        <!-- Main Entry Content -->
    {/exp:channel:entries}
        <div class="pagination bottom">  
        {exp:channel:next_entry channel="work" url_title="{segment_1}"}  
            <a href="{path='site_index'}" class="left">Next - {title}</a>  
        {/exp:channel:next_entry}  
        {exp:channel:prev_entry channel="work" url_title="{segment_1}"}  
            <a href="{path='site_index'}" class="right">Prev - {title}</a>  
        {/exp:channel:prev_entry}  
        </div> 
    </div>
    {/case}  
{/exp:switchee}
```

As you can see I'm using switchee, however I've tested outside of switchee I get the same result.

Comment: can you post your template code?

Comment: @MarkBusnelliJr I've added the template code. Thank you.